# how to add Ant design to next.js 13 project,and customize the theme and components

Tags: themes, less, customization, ant-design-pro, next.js13

What Ant design has done so well is humanizing their design. They evaluate quality of design by measuring against four human-consciousness and happiness centric values - naturalness, certainty, meaningfulness, and growth. Those act as a standard for designers and guide them in decision-making and better judgment.

above para is just a description
pls refer the heading and pls let me know your thought

Answer (score 0):

Just add `import 'antd/dist/reset.css'` in the _app file(in version 5). You can customize the styles by writing antd class names in your global.css file and add your styles. Then import it after antd CSS in your _app file.